# Freshly installed gradle doesn't work showing

Tags: java, gradle

I was wondering how to solve this:

```
**.local ~/Hello  **
╰─➤  gradle run
╰─➤  gradle run   
> Task :compileJava FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':compileJava'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':compileClasspath'.
   > Could not resolve com.google.guava:guava:29.0-jre.
     Required by:
         project :
      > Could not resolve com.google.guava:guava:29.0-jre.
         > Could not get resource 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/google/guava/guava/29.0-jre/guava-29.0-jre.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/google/guava/guava/29.0-jre/guava-29.0-jre.pom'.
               > The server may not support the client's requested TLS protocol versions: (TLSv1.2, TLSv1.3). You may need to configure the client to allow other protocols to be used. See: https://docs.gradle.org/8.0.2/userguide/build_environment.html#gradle_system_properties
                  > PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 405ms
1 actionable task: 1 executed
```

```
**java -version **                                                                                          1 ↵
openjdk version "1.8.0_362"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Corretto-8.362.08.1 (build 1.8.0_362-b08)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Corretto-8.362.08.1 (build 25.362-b08, mixed mode)
```

I'm trying to run the following test file.

```
/*
 * This file was generated by the Gradle 'init' task.
 *
 * This generated file contains a sample Java project to get you started.
 * For more details take a look at the Java Quickstart chapter in the Gradle
 * User Manual available at https://docs.gradle.org/6.5/userguide/tutorial_java_projects.html
 */

plugins {
    // Apply the java plugin to add support for Java
    id 'java'

    // Apply the application plugin to add support for building a CLI application.
    id 'application'
}

repositories {
    // Use jcenter for resolving dependencies.
    // You can declare any Maven/Ivy/file repository here.
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    // This dependency is used by the application.
    implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:29.0-jre'

    // Use JUnit Jupiter API for testing.
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:5.7.2'
}

application {
    // Define the main class for the application
    mainClass = 'hello.App'
}

test {
    // Use junit platform for unit tests
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

**gradle -version **

---

### Gradle 8.0.2

Build time:   2023-03-03 16:41:37 UTC
Revision:     7d6581558e226a580d91d399f7dfb9e3095c2b1d

Kotlin:       1.8.10
Groovy:       3.0.13
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.10.11 compiled on July 10 2021
JVM:          1.8.0_362 (Amazon.com Inc. 25.362-b08)
OS:           Mac OS X 13.2.1 aarch64`

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

The gradle error does suggest some possible reason:

> The server may not support the client's requested TLS protocol
> versions: (TLSv1.2, TLSv1.3). You may need to configure the client to
> allow other protocols to be used. See:
> https://docs.gradle.org/8.0.2/userguide/build_environment.html#gradle_system_properties

If that is the true reason, you need to probably allow TLSv1.1. But given this is maven central, I would expect it should not require any additional configuration for most of the time.

Try install a different/later version of Java instead of the 1.8 and the Amazon one. Amazon Corretto has its own security patches:

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/opensource/tls-1-0-1-1-changes-in-openjdk-and-amazon-corretto/

Comment: It seems to be the same question:

Comment: > Could not resolve com.google.guava:guava:29.0-jre.
         > Could not get resource 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/google/guava/guava/29.0-jre/guava-29.0-jre.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/google/guava/guava/29.0-jre/guava-29.0-jre.pom'.
               > The server may not support the client's requested TLS protocol versions: (TLSv1.2, TLSv1.3). You may need to configure the client to allow other protocols to be used. See: https://docs.gradle.org/8.0.2/userguide/build_environment.html#gradle_system_properties

Comment: I'm using 
```
 java -version                                                                                            1 ↵
openjdk version "1.8.0_362"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Corretto-8.362.08.1 (build 1.8.0_362-b08)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Corretto-8.362.08.1 (build 25.362-b08, mixed mode)
```
now